# How to skip deps when running rebar ct?

Tags: erlang, rebar

I've got a `rebar.config` file that looks like this:

```
{sub_dirs, ["apps/app1", "apps/app2"]}.
{lib_dirs, ["deps"]}.
{deps, [
        %% etc.
   ]}.
```

When I run `./rebar ct` from the top-level directory, it recurses into the "deps" folder and starts running Common Test in there as well as in my application directories.

Since this increases the build time substantially, and since the dependencies *should* have passed their tests before being released, I'd like rebar not to do this.

How do I get it to only run `ct` (and `eunit`) against my code, ignoring the `deps` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `skip_deps` option:

```
rebar ct skip_deps=true
```

or

```
rebar eunit skip_deps=true
```